# Is it safe to swap two different vectors in C++, using the std::vector::swap method?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stdvector, swap

Suppose that you have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> First{"example", "second" , "C++" , "Hello world" };
    std::vector<std::string> Second{"Hello"};

    First.swap(Second);

    for(auto a : Second) std::cout << a << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Imagine the vector are not `std::string`, yet classes:

```
std::vector<Widget> WidgetVector;

std::vector<Widget2> Widget2Vector;
```

Is it still safe to swap the two vectors with the `std::vector::swap` method: `WidgetVector.swap(Widget2Vector);` or it will lead to an UB?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is safe because nothing is created during the swap operation. Only data members of the class `std::vector` are swapped.

Consider the following demonstrative program that makes it clear how objects of the class `std::vector` are swapped.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>

class A
{
public:
    explicit A( size_t n ) : ptr( new int[n]() ), n( n )
    {
        std::iota( ptr, ptr + n, 0 );   
    }

    ~A() 
    { 
        delete []ptr; 
    }

    void swap( A & a ) noexcept
    {
        std::swap( ptr, a.ptr );
        std::swap( n, a.n );
    }

    friend std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &os, const A &a )
    {
        std::copy( a.ptr, a.ptr + a.n, std::ostream_iterator<int>( os, " " ) );
        return os;
    }

private:    
    int *ptr;
    size_t n;
};

int main() 
{
    A a1( 10 );
    A a2( 5 );

    std::cout << a1 << '\n';
    std::cout << a2 << '\n';

    std::cout << '\n';

    a1.swap( a2 );

    std::cout << a1 << '\n';
    std::cout << a2 << '\n';

    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
0 1 2 3 4 

0 1 2 3 4 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

As you see only data members `ptr` and `n` are swapped in the member function swap. Neither additional resources are used.

A similar approach is used in the class `std::vector`.

As for this example

```
std::vector<Widget> WidgetVector;

std::vector<Widget2> Widget2Vector;
```

then there are objects of different classes. The member function swap is applied to vectors of the same type.

Comment: But what of the OP's *actual* case, where the vectors being swapped are of *different* classes?

Comment: @AdrianMole The member function swap if defined for the given type of the vector. It is not defined for vectors of different types. It is not a template member function.

Comment: "swap is applied to vectors of the same type" You should add an "only" between "is" and "applied".

Comment: Of course, stateful allocators might change things.

Answer (score 22):

Yes, this is perfectly safe to swap vectors of the same type.

Vector under the hood is just a few pointers pointing to the data the vector uses and "end" of the sequence.  When you call swap you just exchange those pointers between the vectors.  You don't need to worry that the vectors are the same size because of this.

Vectors of different types cannot be swapped using `swap`.  You'd need to implement your own function that does the conversion and swapping.

Comment: You need to look more closely at the second part of the question.

Comment: @MarkRansom Yep.  Missed the `2`.  Updated.

Answer (score 13):

> Is it safe to swap two different vectors in C++, using the std::vector::swap method?

Yes. Swapping can generally be considered safe. On the other hand, safety is subjective and relative and can be considered from different perspectives. As such, it is not possible to give a satisfactory answer without augmenting the question with a context, and choosing what sort of safety is being considered.

> Is it still safe to swap the two vectors with the std::vector::swap method: WidgetVector.swap(Widget2Vector); or it will lead to an UB?

There will not be UB. Yes, it is still safe in the sense that the program is ill-formed.

Answer (score 6):

The `swap` function is defined as follows: [`void swap( T& a, T& b );`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap). Note here that both `a` and `b` are (and *have* to be) the **same type**. (There is no such function defined with this signature: `void swap( T1& a, T2& b )`, as it would make no sense!)

Similarly, the `swap()` member function of the `std::vector` class is defined as follows:

```cpp
template<class T1> class vector // Note: simplified from the ACTUAL STL definition
{
//...
public:
    void swap( vector& other );
//...
};
```

Now, as there is no 'equivalent' definition with a template override (see [Explicit specializations of function templates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization)) for the function parameter (which would be of the form: `template <typename T2> void swap(std::vector<T2>& other)`), that parameter *must be* a vector of the same type (template) as the 'calling' class (that is, it must also be a `vector<T1>`).

Your `std::vector<Widget>` and `std::vector<Widget2>` are two ***different*** types, so the call to `swap` won't compile, whether you try to use the member function of either object (as your code does), or using the *specialization* of the `std::swap()` function that takes two `std:vector` objects as parameters.

Comment: `std::vector::swap` is a member function, how can that be a specialisation of a free-standing template function???

Comment: @Aconcagua Although I'm no expert on *exact* terminology, see here: [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/swap2) where the following is stated: "Specializes the `std::swap` algorithm for `std::vector`"

Comment: @AdrianMole While there does exist a specialization for `std::swap`, that is not what the OP is using.  When you do `First.swap(Second);`, you call [`std::vector::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/swap) which is a different function from [`std::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap)

Comment: @Aconcagua OK! I read a bit more: `template< class T, class Alloc >void swap(vector<T,Alloc>& lhs, vector<T,Alloc>& rhs );` ... Calls `lhs.swap(rhs)`

Comment: Sorry, my bad... You're link goes straight to the documentation of std::swap specialisation for vectors. But that's different from [member function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/swap), which exists as well and is used in question (only).

Comment: Reasoning actually is analogous: The member is defined as `void swap(std::vector& other)` (i. e. `std::vector<T>`), not as `template <typename U> void swap(std::vector<U>& other)` (assuming T being type parameter for vector itself).

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica Your comments are very helpful - thank-you! (and see edited answer).

Comment: @Aconcagua I'm trying to find an authoritative reference/link for the 'defaulting' behaviour for the argument type in `void swap( vector& other )` as declared - any clues?

Comment: @AdrianMole Really authoritative only is the [standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents). Next closest might be [current draft version](https://eel.is/c++draft/), then probably cppreference.

Answer (score 4):

You can't swap vectors of two different types but it's a compilation error instead of UB. `vector::swap` only accepts vectors of the same type and allocator.

Not sure if this will work, but if you want a vector containing `Widget2`s converted from `Widget`s you can try this:

```
std::vector<Widget2> Widget2Vector(
    std::make_move_iterator(WidgetVector.begin()),
    std::make_move_iterator(WidgetVector.end())
);
```

`Widget2` will have to be move constructible from `Widget`.

Answer (score 0):

`using std::swap; swap(a, b);` and `a.swap(b);` have the exact same semantics where the latter works; at least for any sane type. All standard types are sane in that regard.

Unless you use an interesting allocator (meaning stateful, not always equal, and not propagated on container swap, see [`std::allocator_traits`](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits)), swapping two [`std::vector`](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)s with the same template-arguments is just a boring swap of three values (for capacity, size, and data-pointer). And swapping basic types, absent data-races, is safe and cannot throw.

That is even guaranteed by the standard. See [`std::vector::swap()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/swap).